# MongoDB Storage size stays higher than uncompressed data size after recapping a collection

Tags: mongodb, storage

Using MongoDB 4.4.6 on a single server instance.

We're using Mongo as an archiving database, if it matters.
We also don't have any MongoDB experts, so if we're doing something horribly wrong, I'd appreciate the feedback.

I'm trying to reduce storage for the DB. Many collections are capped, and I took one to try to reduce its capping.

The original parameters were:

- Max size (capping): 156GB
- Size (uncompressed): ~156GB (very close to the max size)
- Storage size: ~83.3GB (total size was very close to it, as index size was only ~2MB)

I ran a `convertToCapped` command on this collection with size 50GB.

When the conversion finished the max size indeed changed to 50GB, but the storage size (compressed) (which as I understand it was preallocated for this newly capped collection) is around 76.8GB.

Assuming the compression ratio should be roughly the same, then the storage size should be less than 30GB.

How can I cleanup the extra size? I tried running a `compact` command but it freed just a few MBs.

I saw the option to run `repairDatabase()` but this command has so many warnings it doesn't seem like the correct way to do so.

Thanks

**EDIT**

Added filtered collStats, per @rickhg12hs request:

```
"size" : 53686822951.0,
"avgObjSize" : 646494,
"storageSize" : 82426355712.0,
"freeStorageSize" : 3994337280.0,
 "maxSize" : NumberLong(53687091200),
        "total size of bloom filters" : 0,
        "checkpoint size" : 78431825920.0,
        "file allocation unit size" : 4096,
        "file size in bytes" : 82426355712.0,
        "column-store fixed-size leaf pages" : 0,
        "column-store variable-size RLE encoded values" : 0,
        "column-store variable-size deleted values" : 0,
        "column-store variable-size leaf pages" : 0,
        "fixed-record size" : 0,
        "maximum internal page key size" : 368,
        "maximum internal page size" : 4096,
        "maximum leaf page key size" : 2867,
        "maximum leaf page size" : 32768,
        "maximum leaf page value size" : 67108864,
         "Average on-disk page image size seen" : 0,
         "Maximum page size seen" : 0,
         "Minimum on-disk page image size seen" : 0,
         "On-disk page image sizes smaller than a single allocation unit" : 0,
         "Size of the root page" : 0,
         "compressed page maximum internal page size prior to compression" : 4096,
         "compressed page maximum leaf page size prior to compression " : 32768,
         "update value size change" : 0,
         "approximate byte size of timestamps in pages written" : 1159112,
         "approximate byte size of transaction IDs in pages written" : 2935856,
         "tiered storage object size" : 0
            "total size of bloom filters" : 0,
            "checkpoint size" : 1560576,
            "file allocation unit size" : 4096,
            "file size in bytes" : 2600960,
            "column-store fixed-size leaf pages" : 0,
            "column-store variable-size RLE encoded values" : 0,
            "column-store variable-size deleted values" : 0,
            "column-store variable-size leaf pages" : 0,
            "fixed-record size" : 0,
            "maximum internal page key size" : 1474,
            "maximum internal page size" : 16384,
            "maximum leaf page key size" : 1474,
            "maximum leaf page size" : 16384,
            "maximum leaf page value size" : 7372,
            "Average on-disk page image size seen" : 0,
            "Maximum page size seen" : 0,
            "Minimum on-disk page image size seen" : 0,
            "On-disk page image sizes smaller than a single allocation unit" : 0,
            "Size of the root page" : 0,
            "compressed page maximum internal page size prior to compression" : 16384,
            "compressed page maximum leaf page size prior to compression " : 16384,
            "update value size change" : 0,
            "approximate byte size of timestamps in pages written" : 1101688,
            "approximate byte size of transaction IDs in pages written" : 2998128,
            "tiered storage object size" : 0
"totalIndexSize" : 2600960,
"totalSize" : 82428956672.0,
"indexSizes" : {
    "_id_" : 2600960
},
```

Collection wt file size in bytes: 82426355712
Index files size in bytes: 2600960

Comment: I could be wrong, but I think specifying `size` in `convertToCapped` is the actual number of bytes allocated on the storage device.  With compression, you can probably store more in this physical space, but it is compression algorithm and data dependent.

Comment: @rickhg12hs Thanks for the comment, but unfortunately this is incorrect. The size argument is the uncompressed size.

Comment: From [documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/command/convertToCapped/): "*The `convertToCapped` will not recreate indexes from the original collection on the new collection, other than the index on the `_id` field.*" You need to drop and re-create the indexes.

Comment: Interesting!  Would you show the output of `db.runCommand({collStats: "yourCollection"})` and also the actual size in bytes of the `.wt` file for the collection?

Comment: `collStats` can be pretty huge.  I'm no javascript wizard, but in `mongosh` after `use yourDB`, `Object.entries(db.runCommand({collStats: "yourCollection"})).forEach(([key, val]) => {if (key.toLowerCase().includes("size")) {console.log({[key]: val})}})` will show all the top-level size parameters.

Comment: @rickhg12hs Added. Thanks. Please let me know if any other parameters can help and are missing

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Thanks, but unfortunately the index is just a very small fraction of the storage size, and we indeed only use the default index, so it probably won't make any difference.

Comment: Very curious indeed! I don't suppose that running `compact` a few times changes anything much, does it?

Comment: Nope, just tried again. Got OK=1, bytesFreed=0

Comment: I'm wondering what a [`mongodump`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/database-tools/mongodump/)/[`mongorestore`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/database-tools/mongorestore/) of the collection into a new collection would look like.